# what to use with Dns.GetHostAddresses with First() or FirstOrDefault()

Tags: c#, linq, dns

- Which one is better in this case First() or FirstOrDefault() ?
- What will be the result of default if no IP address is found ? will it be
  null ?

  ```
  Dns.GetHostAddresses(hosturl).First().ToString()
  ```

or

```
Dns.GetHostAddresses(hosturl).FirstOrDefault().ToString()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `First()` and `FirstOrDefault()` is only relevant in the case where the collection does not contain any elements.

In that case `First()` throws an exception, whereas `FirstOrDefault()` returns `default(T)` (which is null for a reference type). In your case, the first instruction

```
Dns.GetHostAddresses(hosturl).First().ToString()
```

will therefore throw an exception when the list is empty, while the second instruction

```
Dns.GetHostAddresses(hosturl).FirstOrDefault().ToString()
```

will also throw an exception (a NullReferenceException) if the list is empty, because `ToString()` is called on a null reference.